# Redirection on stripped url on Joomla with sh404sef using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla, url-rewriting

Working on a Joomla website, Did use sh404sef to change the old ending url.html to url/

But then i ofcourse want to do a 301 redirect on the old .html to the new, sh404sef don't do this, i can do it url by url but that's not an option in this case.

Have been trying everything using .htaccess but i can't just get it to work, Don't know if any other thing is in .htaccess or in sh404sef is overriding this, Need a solution.

Here is htaccess

```
   RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /



########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ $1/ [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]




php_flag display_errors off
php_flag register_globals off

php_value memory_limit 64M
```

So to clarify everything

It was > http://www.website.com/page.html

It now is http://www.website.com/page/

When someone hitting in on the old .html url's they get a 404 and it kills both visitors and seo. Did try all the usual commands in htaccess to do this but it do not work. Need suggestions how to solve this !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - before the other rules - but after you first turn on RewriteEngine

```
RewriteCondition  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301]
```

Incidentally - you seem to have multiple instances of RewriteEngine On - which can cause server 500 errors on some servers.

Answer (score 0):

For me work like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /yourfolderjoomla/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```